# Highcharts: Align two Y-Axis with different values

Tags: highcharts

Please take a look at this jsfiddle highcharts example i prepared to show you our case:

http://jsfiddle.net/nogz0j2b/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: 'Test Chart'
},
xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    crosshair: true
}],
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Value 1',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    }
}, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
        text: 'Value 2',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
    opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
series: [{
    name: 'Value 1',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [2.50, 2.50, 2.50, 3.20, 3.20, 3.20, 3.20, 3.20],

}, {
    name: 'Value 2',
    type: 'line',
    data: [150, 85.89, 67.43, 38.12, 12.50, 6.20, 2.20, 1.20],
}]
```

});

Somehow we need to align the two y axis to show the correct time when the 2 lines are crossing and Value 2 is smaller than Value 1. So in my example it would be in July.

Currently it is missleading because the line crossing is earlier because of the difrerent tick positions.

I hope you have some ideas ... thank you!

Comment: Why do you have 2 y-axis when you want the tick positions to be relative to each other? Is it because there will always be this situation where you have 1 decreasing and 1 increasing and you only ever want the crossing point to be the common tick position?

Comment: i guess the only way is to have the same y axis or the same y axis tick points. as written in my other comment, we need a solution where we can have different scales for the y axis, because the crossing point will be around 0.10 - 10, but the decreasing line can start at around 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `linkedTo:0,`  in the secondary yAxis attributes and `type: 'logarithmic',` in both

So yAxis is

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
type: 'logarithmic',
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Value 1',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },

}, { // Secondary yAxis
linkedTo:0 ,
    type: 'logarithmic',
        title: {
            text: 'Value 2',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true,
        tickPositions: [0,1,2,3]
    }],
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/rnmhm2em/)

Comment: Thank you! The problem here is that Value 2 can be a lot higher than Value 1. Value 1 will be around 0,10 - 10 and Value 2 can be > 500. The higher Value 2 is, the less you see the other line because it is attached too much to the bottom.

is it possible to have a kind of logarithmic Y-Axis where we have fixed Tick Points for 1 - 10 and then the rest of the tick points are dynamic and max. 3tick points?

Like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,50,100,250,500

But than i guess there is again the problem that the Tick Points 1-10 are very stacked ...

Comment: You can change axis type to logarithmic wit the type option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type You can set the tick manually or dynamically with tickPositions or tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: thank you very much! and how is it possible that the tick positions are on both y axis the same, so that i really see chrossing lines when the value is the same? in your example it would be in July when the lines should cross.

Comment: i have it ... i just need to add linkedTo:0 to the second y axis! perfect

Comment: correct i forget to add `linkedTo:0` i am updating answer

Comment: If this answer  helped, then close this answer as accepted as instructed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)